# Decompose rational numbers into sum of rational numbers of the form $\frac{1}{a}$.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to show that Given $n>0$ and a rational number $q$ there are only finitely many n-tuples $(c_1,...,c_n)$ of natural numbers such that $q=1/c_1+...+1/c_n$. This result can be used to show that there are finitely many groups with a fixed number of conjugacy classes. i.e, we have a group $G$ of size $lcm(c_1,...,c_n)$ for each n-tuple$(c_1,...,c_n)$ such that $1=\frac{1}{c_1}+\frac{1}{c_2}+...+\frac{1}{c_n}$.

Ok so for example, when $n=5$ and $q=1$,  $1=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}$, so $(5,5,5,5,5)$ is a 5-tuple that work. There might be other.We need to show there are finitely many of them.

It is in remark in the following picture:[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close with reading the comments.

Comment: I am baffled by the question. Maybe I am not understanding, but is this not obvious?

Comment: False for non-negative rationals.  Technical difficulty if the rational is 0.   Are the c's ordered by magnitude?  BTW, 3/4 = 1/2 + 1/4.  So think beyond 3/4 = 1/4 + 1/4  + 1/4.

Comment: The $c_i$'s are positive, and we don't care about the order of the $c_i$'s. I don't understand why is this obvious?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the question is clear enough, and not obvious. But it would be nice to have a bit more context for the question, such that it doesn't feel like we're just doing someone's homework for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *smallest* $c_i$ must be at most $\frac{n}{q}$ -- otherwise the $\frac1{c_i}$ are all so small that the sum of them cannot reach $q$. Therefore there are only finitely many choices for what the smallest $c_i$ can be. For each of those choices, use induction on $n$ to conclude that there are only finitely many ways to fill out the *rest* of the $c_j$s.

Comment: Shouldn't your $\frac{1}{qn}$ be $\frac{n}{q}$?

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, indeed.

Comment: I understand the logic now, But I don't see the picture fully yet. Like I do not know why you thought about using the fact that $c_i \le \frac{n}{q}$

Comment: @mathnoob: Once I decided on "use induction" (which is a strategy that's useful in a lot of cases so it deserves to be tried here) the point would be to find _something_ that there was only finitely many workable choices for, such that each of them would yield finitely many of the total outcomes in the induction hypothesis where we have a possibly-different $q$ to meet for a smaller $n$. From there to "look at the smallest of the $c_i$s" was a matter of throwing stuff at the wall for a few minutes until something stuck.

Comment: (Oh, and the particular value $\frac nq$ was something I calculated backwards after thinking "if the $c_i$s are all _too large_, then the sum of their reciprocals will not be big enough, so there must be _some_ limit to what the smallest one can be". I tried to do it in my head at first and got a wrong formula until TonyK corrected me).